# Code to walk a MSAA tree for a given window (Microsoft Active Accessibility)? In C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, accessibility

Any links to code to get the control tree? Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't receiving answers that satisfy your problem, consider elaborating on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an HWND, you can use [AccessibleObjectFromWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317978(VS.85).aspx) to get the IAccessible interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the answer from jeffamaphone:

Use AccessibleObjectFromWindow() to get an IAccessible object on which you can use the AccessibleChildren() method to get the children and thus be able to walk the accessiblity tree.